# Django form : two users (A and B) - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Exception Value Channel has no seller

Tags: django

I'm facing an issue. My goal is to know if a user already exist in DB. If it's true add it to the channel and create it.

There is only two fields in the form for consumer.

- title of channel
- name of seller (check if it's valid and if so add it)

I don't really why that does not work.

```
class CreateChannelView(CreateView):
model = Channel
form_class = CreateChannelForm
template_name = 'channel_new.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.consumer = self.request.user
    sellers = self.request.POST.get("seller")
    current_seller = User.objects.filter(username=sellers)
    if current_seller.count()<1:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username does not exist')
    else:
        existed_seller = User.objects.get(username=sellers)
        form.instance.seller.add(existed_seller)
    form.save()
    return super(CreateChannelView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('channel:channel_home')

class Channel(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_seller")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.name))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my template with the form. I'm using classical field form and I add one field called seller which is related to my channel model

```
<form method="post" class="user-log">
{% csrf_token %}     
{% for field in form %}
<div class="mt-10">
{{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="mt-10">
<input type="text" name="seller" placeholder="Mike" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Jean'" required="" class="single-input">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="" value=" Add a new channel">        
</form>
```

ERROR:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /channel/new/
Exception Value: Channel has no seller.

Trace: 
 form.instance.seller.add(existed_seller) 

__class__   
<class 'channel.views.CreateChannelView'>
current_seller  
<QuerySet [<User: fredo>]>
existed_seller  
<User: fredo>
form    
<CreateChannelForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(name)>
self    
<channel.views.CreateChannelView object at 0x2b00798d3350>
sellers 
'fredo'
```

Comment: Why not make `seller` a part of the `CreateChannelForm`? Validating and cleaning input is exactly what a Django form is all about.

Comment: I've try to do it with crispy form but the thing is I did not manage to get an input where I can write the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer :)

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.consumer = self.request.user
    sellers = self.request.POST.get("seller")
    current_seller = User.objects.filter(username=sellers)
    if current_seller.count()<1:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username does not exist')
    else:
        existed_seller = User.objects.get(username=sellers)
        form.instance.seller = existed_seller #here is the chnage
    form.save()
    return super(CreateChannelView, self).form_valid(form)
```